# Lots of threads missing in Users.threads.list()

Tags: gmail-api

I am retrieving threads from my GMail account using the Users.threads.list method, with the query "in:sent newer_than:1y". The first page of results (100 threads) looks OK, with threads from Dec 2014 and Jan 2015. However, the second page starts at June 2014, and goes back to May 2014 etc. It looks like whole pages of threads are missing for the months of July-November 2014.

I have reproduced this using the in-page API tester at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list.

Everything looks fine in GMail's web interface.

I'm pretty sure this worked yesterday, i.e. I was able to retrieve all threads / emails of 2014.

Comment: I tried same query using API tester, I was able to retrieve threads in the patterns jan 5- aug 19

aug 16-jun 29th

jun 27th- april 2

april 2- jan 14th. threads.list sorts the data in DESC ordered by thread date(not the latest update date). Can you check whether the threads that was missed was completely gone from response or its in the next page(like 3rd or 4th)?

Comment: The missing threads definitely do not show up in later pages.

Comment: OK, it works again now.

Comment: As of Jan 15 2015: The problem did not occur again, it has been working as expected for the last week.

UPDATE Feb 24 2015: It is occurring again right now

Comment: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3735

Comment: Pretty sure gmail just made some changes to their api. resultSizeEstimate for threads.list is no longer working as of this morning.

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?

Comment: As of now, everything works as expected, i.e. I see no gaps in threads. I'll post here if I see the problem again

Comment: @DanielFalabella if you think there's a new issue with resultSizeEstimate on threads.list can you either open a new post about it or if you have a reproducible test case and it definitely seems like a bug feel free to just report it to the issue tracker:  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=API%3DGmail

Comment: @EricDeFriez thanks for the suggestion.  I actually submitted it several days ago: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3819&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner