# User.threads.list returns not all threads

Tags: gmail-api

I trying to get all threads for my test user.
Accordingly to user profile(Users.getProfile), "threadsTotal" = 45771

So, I expecting to get 45771 threads for Users.threads.list.
But, I am getting only 599 results.

I using following params in request:

```
:fields => "threads(id),nextPageToken",
:includeSpamTrash => true, 
:userId => "me", 
:maxResults => '100'
```

In logs I see 6 successful api calls.(100+100+100+100+100+99 results)

With :maxResults => '20' I getting only 319 results.(With 16 successful api calls)

How I can get all threads for my user?

Comment: Do you just want to get the thread ids with User.threads: list, or are you also trying to get the thread contents with Users.threads: get?

Comment: I tried in API explorer to check the threads.list, I am able to fetch all the threads, Try here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list let me know if you still see the error

Comment: Exactly the same results in API explorer. Get Profile shows "threadsTotal": 45771, Thread list returns only 590 items

Comment: Do you see a gap in the thread dates? Same or similar problem is mentioned here [Lots of threads missing in Users.threads.list()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824047/lots-of-threads-missing-in-users-threads-list) 
(I'd mark your question as duplicate, but it looks like I don't have enough reputation for that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be related to the number of threads in the trash and the spam folder.  I found the discrepancy between the threadsTotal value in the response to users.get_profile and threads.list.count to be equal to the number of threads in the trash.

I also checked users.get_profile.messageCount and messages.list.count and found a similar result.

This problem disappears for me when I set :includeSpamTrash to be false in the users.threads.list parameters.